# new column is the sum of two consecutive rows

Tags: pandas, sum, cumsum

please your gentile help, anyone can help me with pandas-python

I need a new column, this new column is the sum of two consecutive rows, (figure)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzWNz.png)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the `table.assign(<new column> = <formula>)` function to build out your dataframe.